# Getting Forbidden on nginx "/" url path even though other urls work fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, vite

I deployed my node/react/vite app on an ec2 instance using this code

Node index.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("frontend/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running ${PORT}`);
});
```

which I run on a ec2 instance with the build file there

Nginx config
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/#removed for privacy#/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/#removed for privacy#/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.#removed for privacy#) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = #removed for privacy#) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name #removed for privacy# www.#removed for privacy#;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: ssl certification, other routes, cookies, and internal redirects work properly